# Windows 7 BSOD ntoskrnl.exe

Tags: windows-7, bsod

One of my laptops keep on crashing and when I used Nirsoft's utility to check the minidumps, the Crash Address column always show ntoskrnl.exe+? where? appears to be a hexadecimal address of some sort.

The Bug Check String column can be anything such as `SYSTEM_SERVICE_EXCEPTION`, `BAD_POOL_CALLER`, `PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`, `IRQ1_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL`, `DRIVER_CORRUPTED_EXPOOL`, `MEMORY_MANAGEMENT`, etc.

Any idea why?

The laptop was originally purchased with Windows Vista installed.  It's a **`Vostro 1400 model`**. I am running Windows 7 now.  Will this be due to incompatibility between the hardware and software or something else?

Comment: Bad image installed?  Wipe it and reimage.  Bad RAM? Run [MemTest86+](http://www.memtest.org/).

Comment: The majority of the hardware that came with `Windows Vista` supports `Windows 7`.  The error codes you are getting point toward a device problem.  Is this a new problem?

Comment: upload the dmp files so that we can see more.